# sql order by query is not working correctly

Tags: sql

The SQL select query is shown below. It's working, but the first row it is returning is wrong. Expected result is also shown below.

Why does this happen? Can you solve this problem ?

```
SELECT pid, pname, pcost
FROM Product
JOIN SubCategory ON Product.subcate_id = SubCategory.subcate_id
JOIN Category ON SubCategory.cate_id = Category.cate_id
WHERE Category.cate_id = 1 order by pcost
```

The result set is

```
pid         pname           pcost
----------- --------        --------------
16          hp-dreamscreen  23232
25          imac-pc-parts   234
35          imac            2349
9           Apple_cinema_   30000
14          hp-bu178aa      30000
15          lenovo-c200     32111
17          imac            345345

(7 row(s) affected)
```

You can see the problem in result set in the 1st row - it should appear at after imac (3rd row) as defined by the `order(pcost)`

Comment: sql server / mysql / postgresql / oracle / nosql / sqlite ??

Comment: What **datatype** is the `pcost` column? I bet it's a string type - which is **NOT** sorted numerically, of course - but as string.

Comment: Don't fix the query. **Fix the data**

Comment: @pod Maybe? But changing the column type and fixing data may not be trivial. It could be a 3rd party package that used to expect `pcost = [high|med|low]` but has been repurposed for numeric values. Maybe there are still valid strings in other partitions of data. Who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Why in the world are you storing `pcost` as a (VAR)Char type?
For SQLite / MySQL, you can use `1*` to coerce numerics into numbers.

```
SELECT pid, pname, pcost
FROM Product
JOIN SubCategory ON Product.subcate_id = SubCategory.subcate_id
JOIN Category ON SubCategory.cate_id = Category.cate_id
WHERE Category.cate_id = 1
order by 1*pcost
```

For SQL Server, you'll need to play safe and only coerce numerics. This is easy from SQL Server 2012 onwards using [TRY_CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)

```
order by TRY_CONVERT(int, pcost)
```

Comment: sir can I ask, is there are differnce between multiplying it by 1 as the server automatically cast string to numeric than directly casting it to numeric?

Comment: "automatically"? If it did, it would have sorted correctly wouldn't it. If you mean compared to your `CAST`, it's just my preference.

Answer (score 1):

pcost is probably a varchar column.

Try casting it yo int `cast (pcost  as int)`

Comment: I think a better solution would be fixing the data rather than fixing the query :)

Comment: sure, agree with you, but making a string column integer may not be an option due to the application that may interact with this table. Imagine the amount of checks and tests that must be done to avoid things from breaking

Answer (score 0):

If the data type of `pcost` is not numeric. Convert it to numeric datatype. Try this,

```
SELECT...
FROM..
WHERE..
ORDER BY CAST(pcost as INT)
```

if you are using `MySQL`

```
SELECT...
FROM..
WHERE..
ORDER BY CAST(pcost as SIGNED)
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the data type of the pcost column? if it's varchar or something related the the ordering is correct, try changing the type to numeric.